# An algorithm for a short-notation relating to permutations

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose, for example, that I have a lock with $d=2$ dials, and each dial has $s=3$ settings: $0, 0.5, 1$. The permutations for the lock are thus as follows:

```
0   0
0.5 0
1   0
0   0.5
0.5 0.5
1   0.5
0   1
0.5 1
1   1
```

But suppose that $ \{0, 0.5\} $ is equivalent to $\{0.5, 0\}$, $\{1, 0.5\}$ is equivalent to $\{0.5, 1\}$, and more generally, that each permutation containing exactly the same settings irrespective of order, are equivalent. As such, a short-notation for the list of permutations is:

```
0   0   1
0.5 0   2
1   0   2
0.5 0.5 1
1   0.5 2
1   1   1
```

where the last column is the number of permutations equivalent to the permutation described by the first two columns.

Can this short-notation be generated, in general (i.e., for $n$ and $s$ of various integers), without needing to generate the entire list of permutations? If so, I would be very interested to learn about the algorithm that achieves this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there may be more sophisticated schemes, but you could just list the entries alphabetically (and you list each entry alphabetically internally as well). For example, with $d=4$ and $s=3$, you get this list. For each entry the repetition number is the multinomial coefficient $d!/(x!y!z!...)$ where the entry contains $x$ many a's, $y$ many b's, $z$ many c's, etc.

aaaa  1

aaab  4

aaac  4

aabb  6

aabc  12

aacc  6

abbb  4

abbc  12

abcc  12

accc  4

bbbb  1

bbbc  4

bbcc  6

bccc  4

cccc  1

I'm not sure of the algorithm for generating this list, but it's shouldn't be too hard to do by recursion, I imagine (sorry, I'm not much of a programmer)

Comment: I would certainly be interested in knowing how this recursive process could work without visiting each of the non-sorted permutations too.

Comment: Something like this: to get each entry for {a,b,c} of length 4: (1) 'a' followed by each entry for {a,b,c} of length 3, (2) 'b' followed by each entry for {b,c} of length 3, (3) 'c' followed each entry for {c} of length 3. The "each entry for {...} of length k" are recursive calls, so there three parameters for the procedure, the initial point, the finite set, and the length. Inside the procedure you'll be concatenating the returned strings with the initial point and returning those strings. The repetition numbers can be computed when it's all over, i guess, since that doesn't need recursion.